# Guide To use special characters in Logitech mx keys azerty for mac

Tags: macos, mac, logitech-keyboard

I would like to know or a guide To use special characters like curly braces, square brackets, back slash etc in Logitech mx keys azerty for mac.

Usage: I couldn't able to use the characters that are there in the number keys for example (IN THE BELOW 2nd Image) to use curly braces by pressing OPTION + 4 doesn't work.

Could you please help me with this?

[image: MX Keyboard AZERTY]

[image: OPTION + 4 Doesn't work]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact  model of your keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that it's a PC keyboard with some small concessions to being Mac-compatible.  It's not a 'proper' Mac keyboard. This type of keyboard tends to be marked up how Windows users expect things to be. This one looks more of a mash-up between the two, in quite a confusing way.

If you look in your Input Sources system pref/setting, or the on-screen keyboard, you'll see macOS French has regular brackets ( and ) on  <kbd>5</kbd>   and  <kbd>°</kbd>  , curly brackets { and } are on  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>    <kbd>5</kbd>   and  <kbd>°</kbd> 
Numbers are accessed using Shift on a French AZERTY, the only language I know of that does it that way.

[image]
[image]
[image]

BTW, I would also check that your F-key/special function keys behave as they should, with & without Fn.

Comment: Yep, Thanks a lot for your comment, I changed the Input source to 'French - PC' in Keyboard settings and the special characters work fine when combined with the OPTION keys. Thanks a lot once again.